React Element with HTML Parameters Not Rendering
On a page, I have a element embedded in HTML:
{dataTable}

Which is initialised as:
  const [dataTable, setDataTable] = useState(<p>Data Table Loading...</p>);

And updated in a useEffect function, where I make a database(supabase PostgreSQL) call, to get data for to-do items.
let dataTable = <DataTable todos={todos} todoLogs={todoLogs} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo}></DataTable>

setDataTable(dataTable)

But when it's embedded in the page, nothing shows up and I don't get any errors.
Other elements with a siple structure like </h1>Hello World</h1> , do show up on the page, and when using useState() etc, just like dataTable
When I console.log() the dataTable element, I get:
Browser Console console.log(dataTable) output
Object
$$typeof
: 
Symbol(react.element)
key
: 
null
props
: 
{todos: null, todoLogs: null, deleteTodo: ƒ, toggleTodo: ƒ}
ref
: 
null
type
: 
class DataTable
_owner
: 
null
_store
: 
{validated: true}
_self
: 
undefined
_source
: 
{fileName: 'C:/Users/user123/Desktop/coding-projects/2 }} testin…}/{{REACT}}/table-todo-testing/src/pages/Home.jsx', lineNumber: 132, columnNumber: 21}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

If you're interested, here is what the DataTable component class looks like:
class DataTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.todos = props.todos
        this.todoLogs = props.todoLogs
        this.deleteTodo = props.deleteTodo

      }


  render() {

    const data = this.todoLogs;
    

    // Map over the data to generate table rows

    try {

      const tableRows = data.map((todoLog) => (


        <tr key={todoLog.id}>
          <td>{this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id).title}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d09_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d08_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d07_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d06_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d05_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d04_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d03_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d02_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><button><i className="material-icons" onClick={() => {this.deleteTodo(todoLog.id)}}>delete</i></button></td>
        </tr>
      ));

      return (
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>09/04</th>
              <th>08/04</th>
              <th>07/04</th>
              <th>06/04</th>
              <th>05/04</th>
              <th>04/04</th>
              <th>03/04</th>
              <th>02/04</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {tableRows}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
     

    } catch (error) {

      console.log("22 could not render table, data not available", error)

    }

    // Render the table with the generated rows
    
  }
}

Thanks
I've tried:

Researching the problem

Experimenting embedding other html elements, and getting the results

Ensuring the other parts of the code are error free



Looks like your DataTable component is invalid.
Try to remove the try/catch block in the render component to make sure that you return something (which is not the case in the catch block).
class DataTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Table</p>
  }
}


thanks, that seems to get the table displaying - still can't seem to get the table to update dynamically when the database is upated though...
I wonder if it's something to do with how it's embedded in the html...

Can you update your question with the db call?

In addition, are you able to log props.todos in your data table component ?

I've made the displaying issue a seperate post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78399252/element-not-updating-in-dom-after-its-react-state-is-changed
If you're happy, I'll mark this as the correct solution? @devpolo
