Element Not Updating in DOM After its React State is Changed
I have a react variable called dataTable managed with useState() that holds a table element, embedded in the HTML in my site as {dataTable}.
However, when I update it with setDataTable(), it's value does change and I can check that with console.log(), but it doesn't update in the DOM for some reason.
All other, more simple elements like number variables will update in the DOM when displayed in the same way.
I update the table with:
setDataTable(
  <DataTable
    todos={todos}
    todoLogs={todoLogs}
    deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
    toggleTodo={toggleTodo}
  ></DataTable>
)

The DataTable class looks like:
class DataTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.todos = props.todos;
    this.todoLogs = props.todoLogs;
    this.deleteTodo = props.deleteTodo;
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.todoLogs;

    // Map over the data to generate table rows
    try {
      const tableRows = data.map((todoLog) => (
        <tr key={todoLog.id}>
          <td>{this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id).title}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d09_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d08_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d07_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d06_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d05_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d04_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d03_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" onChange={() => {this.todos.find(x => x.id === todoLog.id)}} checked={todoLog.d02_04_24}></input></td>
          <td><button><i className="material-icons" onClick={() => {this.deleteTodo(todoLog.id)}}>delete</i></button></td>
        </tr>
      ));

      return (
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>09/04</th>
              <th>08/04</th>
              <th>07/04</th>
              <th>06/04</th>
              <th>05/04</th>
              <th>04/04</th>
              <th>03/04</th>
              <th>02/04</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
        </table>
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return <p>Table Loading...</p>;
    }
  }
}

Is there something special about updating React components, or HTML elements with parameters that I don't know?
Thank you.

Generally you don't set state variables to React components - your component state consists of your data, with the appropriate JSX that turns that data into components only during the render pass. Storing components can lead to all sorts of fun problems, and is almost certainly at play here (React almost certainly does rerun but sees a component that hasn't outwardly changed, and so doesn't rerender) so: Is there a reason you're not storing your data as data? (Also, try to show enough code to either be a [mcve], or be close enough to an MRE so that folks can properly see what you're doing)

(and note that you need to show the component that uses <DataTable> in your post, because that's missing right now)

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks, I updated the question with some of your edits, especially the code. Working on the rest, just investigating the problem more to get an answer.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans would storing data as data, just mean adding a <DataTable></DataTable> directly into the code?
Like this: { (todos && todoLogs) ? <DataTable todos={todos} todoLogs={todoLogs} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo}></DataTable> : <p>Loading...</p> }
If that's that case, I tried the above, but it's giving me the same problem of not showing in the DOM.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans when you say "show the component that uses <DataTable>, I just set the dataTable variable to that as shown in the first code block, I don't use it anywhere else, is that what you meant?

Yeah, you'd have something like const [ todoData, setToDoData ] = useState({}); so you don't build a component and save it to state, instead using setToDoData({ todos, todoLogs, ... }) (or you have separate state variables for the separate data collections, which makes more sense if they can change independently of each other) and then you change the actual render return to have a <DataTable ...todoData/> so that React can properly diff it during rerenders.

Your component is not unmounted/remounted. So the changes in the props are not reflected, because you have cached them in the constructor.
There is not need to cache the values for this component.
So, one solution would be to just use the props directly.
class DataTable extends React.Component {
 // no constructor

  render(){
    const {todoLogs:data, todos, deleteTodo}  = this.props;

    ...
  }
}

(so in reality you do not need to use a class at all, you could use a function component)

Another option is to use the componentDidUpdate and check if a prop has changed, and if so, update your local cached versions (you should also use state for those and not store them directly on this).

Finally you could just add a key on the DataTable component to trigger unmount/remount (not the most performant approach)
setDataTable(
  <DataTable
    key={Date.now().toString()}
    todos={todos}
    todoLogs={todoLogs}
    deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
    toggleTodo={toggleTodo}
  ></DataTable>
)


Note that the latter option is definitely not "the React way" to do things though. State is data, not components: forming virtual dom components is the job of the rendering pass (and then those get their data updated as needed during rerenders: if you're unmounting and remounting, you're literally fighting React, its power comes from updating DOM nodes in place even if all their data changed. That's what makes it fast)

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah, I used the first way by removing the values from the constructor

That's a good start, but you'll want to "not create the component" up front in the parent, and only create it as part of the render return, so you're sticking to React conventions.

Everything that @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans says is right. Storing an instance of a component in the state is not a good approach. If you post where/how you use the actual state variable that contains the DataTable we could suggest how to better use it directly in the render flow.

@GabrielePetrioli @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think I have changed things so the component is only created as part of the render return as: {(todos && todoLogs) ? <DataTable todos={todos} todoLogs={todoLogs} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo}></DataTable> : <p>Loading...</p>}
I previously had the state variable embedded in my site as: return (<div>{dataTable}</div>)
